# Sum of series in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a personal Excel spreadsheet for tracking various accounts. Each account has it's own sheet in Excel. I have a chart on one sheet that I was able to include data series for each account.  I would like to add a series to the chart that represents the sum of the accounts over time.  Please advise.

Comment: Due to the vagueness of this question this is how I am interpreting it. You have multiple accounts (Sheets 1 through 3) and a data point in A1 of each. You would like to see the sum of A1 in a chart. This can be achieved on sheet 4 via, =Sheet1!A1+Sheet2!A1+Sheet3!A1. Then you can graph it. Is that an accurate assessment of the problem?

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. This is the right idea.  I would like to track and chart the "sum of A1" for every month, adding a new data point every month.  I have a few years worth of data and intend to continue adding to it.  I already have a chart that includes a line for each individual account over time, but would like to add a sum of all accounts line over time.  I imagine I could make something work with your original response, but if there is a shorter path I would be very interested to hear it.